# How to use docker remote api to create a container using another container's network namespace

Tags: docker, docker-network

I can run the following command to make a container using another container's network namespace:

```
docker run -it --net=container:<container_name> ubuntu:14.04
```

After running it, the two container have the same IP address. I want to know how to use the docker remote api or other client api to do it.

My docker server&client version is 1.10.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker run` is basically `docker create` followed by `docker start`. You can find the documentation for the `/containers/create` endpoint in the [API reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/#create-a-container).

The property you're looking for is the `NetworkMode` in the `HostConfig`;

> **NetworkMode** - Sets the networking mode for the container. Supported standard values are: `bridge`, `host`, `none`, and `container:<name|id>`. Any other value is taken as a custom network’s name to which this container should connect to.